# Simple javascript: arrays, and form information gathering #2

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know javascript much at all, I just like making lists for myself. I am currently trying to create a html page that I can keep track of characters from my favorite game, but I have run across a couple of problems I don't know how to solve.

```
<form name="inputNightlife" id="inputNightlife">
<h2>Nightlife</h2>
<label for="traits"><b>Traits:</b></label><br>
<select multiple="true" name="traits" id="traits">
        <option value="Cologne">Cologne</option>
        <option value="Stink">Stink</option>
        <option value="Fatness">Fatness</option>
        <option value="Fitness">Fitness</option>
    </select>
<label for="turnOns"><b>Turn Ons:</b></label><br>
<select multiple="true" name="turnOns" id="turnOns">
        <option value="Blonde Hair">Blonde Hair</option>
        <option value="Red Hair">Red Hair</option>
        <option value="Brown Hair">Brown Hair</option>
        <option value="Black Hair">Black Hair</option>
    </select>
    <p>Select all that apply.</p>
<nav id="box8" class="hide"><table id="menu3"><tr><td rowspan="2" id="soft">
<textarea name="source8" onclick="this.focus();this.select()" cols="40" rows="3" id="result">
</textarea></td><td>
<input type="button" value="Get Code!" onclick="javascript:generateNightlife();"></td>
<td rowspan="2" id="softA">
<img src="./forSCV/icons/nightlife.png" alt="Nightlife" title="Nightlife" id="arrow" onclick="toggle('box8');">
</td></tr><tr><td>
<input type="button" value="Test Code" onclick="javascript:displayNightlife(this.form);">
</td></tr></table></nav></form>
```

When I click the button, the document.results.endresults.value appears in the  text area. I can then copy the results, and save them as html. This is intended to be a page generator (the best I can come up with).

I am not sure how to make traits and turnOns automatically create an array (with spaces) of the chosen options that will then print in the document.result.endresult.value. I did find several different ways to create an array from the forms, but not how to then get it to go into the document.result.endresult.value.

One way [Google](http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/tutorial004.html).  And another way [Google](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-get-select.phtml)

Adding...

Ok, I reworked my html to include names and id's, and I found a little better page generator, so I was trying to get that to work. Now I have tried this.

```
function byId(idStr){return document.getElementById(idStr);}

function getFormValues() {
var traitsSelectElem = byId('traits');
var turnOnsSelectElem = byId('turnOns');
var chosenTraits = getSelectedOptions(traitsSelectElem);
var chosenTurnOns = getSelectedOptions(turnOnsSelectElem);
var i, n, outputStr;
n = chosenTraits.length;
outputStr = '';
for (i = 0; i < n; i ++)
{
    if (outputStr != ".")
        outputStr += ", ";
    outputStr += chosenTraits[i].value;
}
byId('traitsOutput').innerText = outputStr;

n = chosenTurnOns.length;
outputStr = '';
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if (outputStr != '.')
        outputStr += ', ';
    outputStr += chosenTurnOns[i].value;
}
byId('turnOnsOutput').innerText = outputStr;
}
function getSelectedOptions(selectElem) {
var i, nOptions = selectElem.options.length;
var result = [];
for (i = 0; i < nOptions; i++)
{
    if (selectElem.options[i].selected)
    {
        result.push(
                        {
                            value: selectElem.option[i].value
                        }
                    );
    }
}
return result;
}

function generateNightlife() {

//nightlife
var traits = getFormValues();
var turnOns = getFormValues();
turnOff = document.inputNightlife.turnOff.value;
perfumeDuration = document.inputNightlife.perfumeDuration.value;
lovePotion = document.inputNightlife.lovePotion.value;

outputNightlife = "<a name='nightlife'></a>\n<div id='easy'>\n<h2>Nightlife</h2>\n
<table class='ntlf'><tr><th>Traits:</th><td class='white'>"+traits+"
</td></tr><tr><th>Turn Ons:</th><td class='white'>"+turnOnsOutput+"</td></tr><tr><th>
Turn Offs:</th><td class='white'>"+turnOff+"</td></tr></table>\n<p class='up2'>Perfume 
Duration: <span class='colorme'>"+perfumeDuration+"</span></p>\n<p>Love Potion Duration: 
<span class='colorme'>"+lovePotion+"</span></p>\n</div>\n"

document.inputNightlife.source8.value = outputNightlife;

return outputNightlife;
}
```

When I test it with chrome it says it cannot set property of .innerText of null which I think is because I don't want it to go to a div. I would like the value returned back to function generateNightlife so that it can be added to the outputNightlife. I don't know how to do that, and I need some help.

Comment: Use document.result.endresult.innerHTML instead

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fully worked example that will pull multiple selections from a select element, before going on to construct an array with them, and finally printing them to screen.

Either of the two tutes you linked to are okay - it's always hard to know what will be obvious, what will need explaining and what will rely on background information that may/may not have already been covered.

I've used a few different tricks here and there are many that are more sophisticated I've elected to eschew. I hope the comments make the operation clear, though would be happy to add clarification as needed. :)

Here's a runnable snippet:

```js
function byId(idStr){return document.getElementById(idStr);}

function getFormValues()
{
 // 1. get a reference to each of the select elemenets we wish to process
 var mainMealSelectElem = byId('mainSelect');
 var dessertSelectElem = byId('dessertSelect');

 // 2. get an array of all of the selected options in each of our select elements
 var chosenMains = getSelectedOptions(mainMealSelectElem);
 var chosenSweets = getSelectedOptions(dessertSelectElem);
 
 var i, n, outputStr;
 n = chosenMains.length;
 outputStr = '';
 for (i=0; i<n; i++)
 {
  // only add a comma before an element if at least one element already exists
  // this is how we do it when writing a list manually.
  if (outputStr != '')
   outputStr += ", ";
   
  // grab the two values from the array we constructed using the getSelectedOptions function.
  // we said that each array element would have 2 fields, and named them "value" and "textLabel" - both entirely arbitrary name.
  // whatever we named them in the below function is what we need to use to access them here.
  outputStr += chosenMains[i].textLabel + " (" + chosenMains[i].value + ")";
 }
 // set the text content of the target span with the array of chosen stuff.
 byId('mainsOutput').innerText = outputStr;

 
 n = chosenSweets.length;
 outputStr = '';
 for (i=0; i<n; i++)
 {
  if (outputStr != '')
   outputStr += ", ";
  outputStr += chosenSweets[i].textLabel + " (" + chosenSweets[i].value + ")";
 }
 byId('dessertsOutput').innerText = outputStr;
}

// returns an array that consists of <value, text-label> pairs - 1 element for each selected option.
function getSelectedOptions(selectElem)
{
 // aloop counter and the total number of iterations required
 var i, nOptions = selectElem.options.length;
 
 // the empty result array
 var result = [];
 
 // loop through all the options this select element has
 for (i=0; i<nOptions; i++)
 {
  // if the current option is selected, we'll need to extract it's info and add it to the output array
  if (selectElem.options[i].selected)
  {
   result.push( 
       {
        value: selectElem.options[i].value, 
        textLabel: selectElem.options[i].label
       }
      );
  }
 }
 return result;
}
```

```css
div
{
 display: inline-block;
}
.centered
{
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='centered'>
  <form>
   <h2>Select the ones you like</h2>
   <select id='mainSelect' multiple>
    <option value='spag'>Spaghetti</option>
    <option value='satay'>Peanut satay</option>
    <option value='schnitz'>Chicken Schnitzel</option>
   </select>
   <select id='dessertSelect' multiple>
    <option value='1'>Ice-cream</option>
    <option value='2'>Fruit salad</option>
    <option value='3'>Custard</option>
   </select>
  </form>
  <br>
  <button onclick='getFormValues()'>Get chosen values</button>
  <hr>
 </div>
 <br>
 <div>
  Selected main-meals: <span id='mainsOutput'></span><br>
  Selected desserts: <span id='dessertsOutput'></span><br>
 </div>
```

And here's the full (copy/pastable) source:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function byId(idStr){return document.getElementById(idStr);}

function getFormValues()
{
    // 1. get a reference to each of the select elemenets we wish to process
    var mainMealSelectElem = byId('mainSelect');
    var dessertSelectElem = byId('dessertSelect');

    // 2. get an array of all of the selected options in each of our select elements
    var chosenMains = getSelectedOptions(mainMealSelectElem);
    var chosenSweets = getSelectedOptions(dessertSelectElem);

    var i, n, outputStr;
    n = chosenMains.length;
    outputStr = '';
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        // only add a comma before an element if at least one element already exists
        // this is how we do it when writing a list manually.
        if (outputStr != '')
            outputStr += ", ";

        // grab the two values from the array we constructed using the getSelectedOptions function.
        // we said that each array element would have 2 fields, and named them "value" and "textLabel" - both entirely arbitrary name.
        // whatever we named them in the below function is what we need to use to access them here.
        outputStr += chosenMains[i].textLabel + " (" + chosenMains[i].value + ")";
    }
    // set the text content of the target span with the array of chosen stuff.
    byId('mainsOutput').innerText = outputStr;


    n = chosenSweets.length;
    outputStr = '';
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (outputStr != '')
            outputStr += ", ";
        outputStr += chosenSweets[i].textLabel + " (" + chosenSweets[i].value + ")";
    }
    byId('dessertsOutput').innerText = outputStr;
}

// returns an array that consists of <value, text-label> pairs - 1 element for each selected option.
function getSelectedOptions(selectElem)
{
    // aloop counter and the total number of iterations required
    var i, nOptions = selectElem.options.length;

    // the empty result array
    var result = [];

    // loop through all the options this select element has
    for (i=0; i<nOptions; i++)
    {
        // if the current option is selected, we'll need to extract it's info and add it to the output array
        if (selectElem.options[i].selected)
        {
            result.push( 
                            {
                                value: selectElem.options[i].value, 
                                textLabel: selectElem.options[i].label
                            }
                        );
        }
    }
    return result;
}
</script>
<style>
div
{
    display: inline-block;
}
.centered
{
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='centered'>
        <form>
            <h2>Select the ones you like</h2>
            <select id='mainSelect' multiple>
                <option value='spag'>Spaghetti</option>
                <option value='satay'>Peanut satay</option>
                <option value='schnitz'>Chicken Schnitzel</option>
            </select>
            <select id='dessertSelect' multiple>
                <option value='1'>Ice-cream</option>
                <option value='2'>Fruit salad</option>
                <option value='3'>Custard</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <br>
        <button onclick='getFormValues()'>Get chosen values</button>
        <hr>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        Selected main-meals: <span id='mainsOutput'></span><br>
        Selected desserts: <span id='dessertsOutput'></span><br>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this and I cannot get it to go into the document.results.endresults.value. It acts like its not even there. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Going on the code you have above, `document.results` is a form (i.e a form with the name attribute `results`). `endresults` is then the name of a `textarea`. Sooo, if you dont have a form named `results` that contains a textarea (or input type='text') named `endresults`, it wont. Now's a good time to become familiar with your browser's built-in javascript debugger - it would tell you where the problem is in a roundabout way - i.e with the error message something like "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'endresults' of undefined(…)".  It's Ctrl-Shift-I for Chrome. Notice

Comment: (continued) how I've given elements an ID and then used byId(...)? This is a way of getting a reference to an(y) element with an id. To do the same thing, you're using `document.results.endresults` - you need to (a) have a form, (b) have named fields (c) remember the name of the form and the contained input element. Targetting an element by it's id suits me far better than the approach you've used. Either is valid. :) Is this a little clearer now?

Comment: So I need to change the form name=result to form id=result, and change textarea name=endresult to textarea id=endresult, but then would I change the document.result.endresult.value to document.write("")?

Comment: @Nancy76 - if you just change the textarea so that it has an id,(lets say endresult) then you can just do `document.getElementById('endresult').value = someValue;`, where somevalue is either text or a variable that holds text. Since I find document.getElementById a real mouthfull, I wrote that short-cut function `byId` - The code in my example that performs this task is `byId('dessertsOutput').innerText = outputStr;` - I'm using `innerText` instead of `value` because I'm writing to the contents of a div, instead of writing to the value that an input holds - it's basically the same thing (cont)

Comment: (cont) Except a div doesn't have a `value` property and an input element (or a textarea) doesn't have an `innerText` property. Am I helping or confusing you? Perhaps a simple page with 2 inputs and a button would be good to play with. You could input 2 names then when the button is pressed, retrieve them both, add them together and set the result to the innerText of a div (or the value of a textarea) Your code is reasonably complex for your current level and may be an impediment to your increased understanding. :)

Comment: I figured out how to call your function, but I can't seem to get any further. I have tried to change the byId('selectMeal') part to document.inputNightlife.source8.value and the byId('mainsOutput').innerText = outputStr to just mainsOutput = outputStr and got an error, I tried some other ways also, and I just can't manage to get it to work. A little more help please.